# Very Baisc Arm Assembly Questions(add, compare)

Tags: arm, pi

**TLDR: What exactly does bx lr do?**

I have trouble understanding these two following examples:

***Add Example: ***
[image]

I understand that the code "add r0, r0, r1" add r1 to r1 and stores it to register 0. What I do not understand is that how the code "bx lr" knows how
to return r0 without explicitly stating r0.

**Compare Example:**
[image]

Same here I understand that the code "BGT r0_Gt" compares if r0 > r1, and if this is true, the code will skip to r0_gt:  However, how does bx lr know how to return the correct value?

Answer (score 2):

It is defined by the used ABI; for ARM, this is EABI which states in "5.4 Result Return"

> - A Fundamental Data Type that is smaller than 4 bytes is zero- or sign-extended to a word and returned in r0.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf

Answer (score 1):

`bx lr` doesn't return any register at all, it just passes control over back to the caller (in the address in the `lr` register), without modifying any other registers than `pc`.

The caller then knows, based on the calling convention, that on return, the return value will be in the r0 register (depending on the exact type of the return value and the platform's calling convention).

Answer (score 0):

BX simply means branch exchange, it does a branch and can switch modes between arm/thumb if supported for that architecture.  LR is a shortcut for register 14, it is that simple. The branch to the address in r14.

If you look at the bl instruction you see that r14 will be set with the address after the bl instruction, the return address from a function call.

The pair bl something then later bx lr (or mov pc,lr also works if you don't need to change modes and are in arm mode) is how you make function calls in arm.

Answer (score 0):

The processor has very little concept of context (in an abstract sense). It does not know where it came from, what the registers are for, or if it is in a function call/subroutine. The higher level languages and compiler do know this, and use some common standards to make things easier.

A very small number of operations do have a special, well defined purpose. A BL  instruction updates both the 'next instruction to execute' (otherwise known as PC or R15), but also magically updates R14 (the link register).

Exceptions (in V7-A) change a few of the banked core registers around, including the register which is usually used to access the stack, and the link register. This means that exceptions can happen without loosing track of everything else that was going on. Cortex M does things differently, and actually uses the stack to help with the banking (setting R14 to a 'magic value' to indicate if the most recent call was an exception or not).

Unless an instruction interacts with specific registers, CPSR specifically, it probably  doesn't care about the context. Some operations (related to security) will be restricted so they can only happen in privileged states - this is ultimately used to prevent an operating system from the user applications, but usually these will relate to accessing very specific control registers.